# Executing a different query based on case situation

Tags: mysql

I've this query:

```
SELECT r.runk_user_id,
       CASE r.runk_user_id WHEN g.group_player1_user_id THEN 'player 1'
                           WHEN g.group_player2_user_id THEN 'player 2'
                           WHEN g.group_player3_user_id THEN 'player 3'
                           WHEN g.group_player4_user_id THEN 'player 4'
                           ELSE 'no player matches'
       END AS player
FROM   groups g
JOIN   runks r ON g.group_id = r.runk_group_id
```

This will output the following result:

[image]

Instead of the query outputting that result I need it to execute other queries based on what the outcome of that case statement is.

So in case of 'player 1' being the case this query needs to get executed:

```
UPDATE groups AS g1, 
(SELECT (runk_image_rating_total + runk_caption_rating_total + runk_challenge_rating_total) as total, g.group_id
FROM groups g
JOIN runks r
ON g.group_id = r.runk_group_id) AS g2
SET g1.group_player1_standing = g2.total + g1.group_player1_standing
WHERE g1.group_id = g2.group_id
```

In case of 'player 2' this needs to get executed:

```
UPDATE groups AS g1, 
(SELECT (runk_image_rating_total + runk_caption_rating_total + runk_challenge_rating_total) as total, g.group_id
FROM groups g
JOIN runks r
ON g.group_id = r.runk_group_id) AS g2
SET g1.group_player2_standing = g2.total + g1.group_player2_standing
WHERE g1.group_id = g2.group_id
```

This what the tables look like:

[image]

[image]

Etc etc. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I once had to do something similar using the [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement. I tried adapting your code, let me know if it works

```
UPDATE groups AS g1, 
(SELECT (runk_image_rating_total + runk_caption_rating_total + runk_challenge_rating_total) as total, g.group_id
FROM groups g
JOIN runks r
ON g.group_id = r.runk_group_id) AS g2
SET g1.group_player2_standing = CASE
WHEN player = player_1 then g2.total + g1.group_player1_standing
WHEN player = player_2 then g2.total + g1.group_player2_standing
ELSE ''
END 
WHERE g1.group_id = g2.group_id AND player IN (player_1, player_2)
```

Comment: Thanks! But the query returns an error though: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE g1.group_id = g2.group_id AND player IN (player_1, player_2)' at line 9

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans updated my answer, forgot to put the END part.

Comment: Getting this error now: #1054 - Unknown column 'player' in 'where clause'

Comment: In the first query you showed ( the select one ) it returns a column called 'player'. I see it is an alias for r.runk_user_id... Maybe you can adapt it to return it as player or adapt the where clause.

Comment: I've added 2 screenshots of the table schemes.